# Borland C++Builder 6 MDI Application

Tags: c++builder, c++builder-6

I made ​​an mdi application in Borland C++Builder 6.

I made 2 forms:

1. The Main Form
2. Child Form

I set Child Form to **Available Forms**.

When I want to call a Child form. I use the following command:

```
Application->CreateForm(__classid(TChildForm), &ChildForm); //calling Child form
```

Why when I call the command again, child form into 2 like this?

[image]

Comment: Maybe because you are calling `CreateForm`  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, don't use `Application->CreateForm()`, use `new` instead:

```
ChildForm = new TChildForm(this);
```

Second, what you describe is normal.  You are creating a new instance of an independent child form, and that is what you see.  If you don't want another child, then don't create a new one, re-use the one you already have, eg:

```cpp
if (!ChildForm)
{
    ChildForm = new TChildForm(this);
}
// use ChildForm as needed...
```

```cpp
TChildForm *ChildForm = NULL;

__fastcall TChildForm::~TChildForm()
{
    ChildForm = NULL;
}

void __fastcall TChildForm::FormClose(TObject *Sender, TCloseAction& Action)
{
    Action = caFree;
}
```